# What will I miss if I don't explore Mother Base?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Mother Base is huge, and running around a mostly-empty base just to punch my soldiers in the face and increase their morale is something I have no interest in doing. This game already wastes enough of my time with the helicopter transitions.

However, upon capturing a certain character who goes on to become a buddy, I went over to the Medical Wing to see if I could talk to that person. Because I'm bad at finding what I'm looking for, I spent a long time running around there and instead found a door that

> > had Paz inside, and triggered a cutscene and flashback with her.

Are there more hidden cutscenes like that? If so, where (and when) do I have to go on the base to trigger them. Manually checking out each platform every few missions just to see if something new is there is very unappealing.

Comment: I think that scene would fit in the easter egg category. As you say you don't want to go back to mother base to check every part of it just so that you MIGHT get a cutscene. And wouldn't expect Konami and Kojima making that an essential part of the story. They are simply easter eggs and if you want you have the opportunity to go exploring mother base to find these easter eggs.

Comment: While I agree with @P1raten, in that no essential part will be missed, there is still a fair bit more you will miss if you do not visit mother base. Hideo himself said, in an interview, that he put a lot of background things in at mother base. The idea, to paraphrase, was that you should never require visiting mother base throughout the game. But doing so opens up secondary content to immerse the player more.

Comment: Easter egg or not, those kinds of cutscenes are things I'm interested in.

Comment: By the way. Every time you rescue an old Mother Base veteran, you get a new picture which triggers a new scene (not cutscene, though) in the Medical Wing.

Comment: There are a bunch of rough diamonds to be found around Mother Base, you can reveal them on the map by interrogating your soldiers around the base

Answer (score 3):

Community Reported Scenes:

- On first arriving at the Support platform, a scene with Ocelot telling recruits to "forget everything Hollywood taught you" and lightly mocking a detailed (engraved) pistol.

Comment: I wonder if the 'mocking a detailed engraved pistol' is a nod to his introduction scene in Snake Eater

Comment: It is, he apply the advice Naked Snake gave him in MGS3: Use a revolver if you are going to absorb the recoil, and engraving don t give you any tactical advantage, so don t use them in the field.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few - As Jeeva says, there is the one with Ocelot, but there are others, like a few linked with D-Dog, and him growing up (triggered when arriving on the base after rescuing him as a puppy), also if you stay out on the field for extended periods of time, you will get dirty to the point that flies start buzzing round your head - returning to mother base will trigger a cutscene where Ocelot throws a bucket of water over you.

There's lots of small things like that, but yes, I do agree with you - Motherbase is a little empty and you won't gain a whole deal more from exploring it thoroughly.

The only other thing that springs to mind as an incentive to explore is the hidden diamonds that are scattered around that you can pick up for some extra GMP.

Comment: I'd almost argue that the D-Dog growing up ones can't be missed - they happen on arrival to Mother Base, and you don't need to explore anything to get them. Hidden diamonds you can definitely miss, though. I didn't realise how plentiful they were until I did the target practice side missions.

Comment: @Jeeva Side-note, interrogating your soldiers on a platform will cause them to tell you where the diamonds are on that platform.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: Oh, that's awesome.